# AngularJS {{}} placeholder Not Working Within Iframe Tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I'm a stranger in a strange land....

in my source, why does this:

```
Video Url: {{exercise.videos[0].url}}
```

Work by showing the url for the video... but:

```
<iframe src="http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/{{exercise.videos[0].url}}"></iframe>
```

Only puts the '{{exercise.videos[0].url}}' and not the same information as the other?

Answer (score 2):

Because `src` is not evaluated by AngularJS. But `ng-src` is:

```
<iframe ng-src="http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/{{exercise.videos[0].url}}"></iframe>
```

Comment: That ALMOST works... but I get:  <iframe src="http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/{{exercise.videos[0].url}}" ng-src="http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/{{exercise.videos[0].url}}"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not the iframe tag itself, it is the src attribute. When using an angular variable for a src attribute, you need to use the ng-src directive.

```
<iframe ng-src="http://fast.wistia.net.embed.iframe/{{exercise.videos[0].url}}"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The brackets in the first example are a shorthand for the [ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) directive, which roughly speaking only sets the text of an element, rather than acting as a general text replacement in the template like in other template languages.

Answer (score 0):

This restriction is in place due to 'Strict Contextual Escaping' and is a mechanism in place in AngularJS to help prevent XSS and clickjacking.

Take a look here if you want some more information:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

The above comments are correct though and you can use the ngSrc directive to avoid having to work around it, however it looks like you will have to inject the $sce module and use the trustAsResourceUrl() method to get it to work, here is a working fiddle:

HTML:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{exercise.videos[0].url}}"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
$scope.exercise.videos = [{url:$sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/someUrl.html")}];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/glandrum101/a5jxg/2/

Comment: Hmmm this renders as:   <iframe ngsrc="http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/79wqpodvmk"></iframe>  for me.

Comment: @NotaGuruAtAll In the jsFiddle or in your actual code?

Comment: Actually if I view frame source on the jsfiddle I get <iframe ngSrc="http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/{{exercise.videos[0].url}}"></iframe>

Comment: Ah, I see it correctly with inspect element.  However, is ngsrc= going to be understood?

Comment: It won't, my fault. Will have to adjust it later.

Comment: I was unable to get it to work by putting the 'http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/' portion of the URL in the actual ng-src attribute.  However, if you inject the $sce, this will allow you to check this URL in your controller and ng-src will properly be able to render the url through ng-src.  The fiddle is updated.